# More efficient approach to XSLT for-each

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an XSLT which takes a . delimted string and splits it into two fields for a SQL statement:

```
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize(Path,'\.')">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="position() = 1 and position() = last()">SITE = '<xsl:value-of select="."/>' AND PATH = ''</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="position() = 1 and position() != last()">SITE = '<xsl:value-of select="."/>' </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="position() = 2 and position() = last()">AND PATH = '<xsl:value-of select="."/>' </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="position() = 2">AND PATH = '<xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="position() > 2 and position() != last()">.<xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="position() > 2 and position() = last()">.<xsl:value-of select="."/>' </xsl:when>                            
    <xsl:otherwise>zxyarglfaux</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>                 
</xsl:for-each>
```

The results are as follows:

```
INPUT: North         OUTPUT: SITE = 'North' AND PATH = ''
INPUT: North.A       OUTPUT: SITE = 'North' AND PATH = 'A'
INPUT: North.A.B     OUTPUT: SITE = 'North' AND PATH = 'A.B'
INPUT: North.A.B.C   OUTPUT: SITE = 'North' AND PATH = 'A.B.C'
```

This works, but is very lengthy.  Can anyone see a more efficient approach?

Thanks!

Comment: you may be interested in a superior solution. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need to tokenize? Looks like you are just splitting on the FIRST period. In this case, you could just do...

```
<xsl:text>Site = '</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(Path,'.')"/>
<xsl:text>' AND PATH = '</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(Path,'.')"/>
<xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. I don't need to tokenize, but this solution does not handle the first case (where there is no '.').

Comment: Actually, it should. Without a period, `substring-before` will return "North" and `substring-after` will return "" (empty string).

Comment: I was getting an empty string on substring-before.

Comment: Change it to `substring-before(concat(Path, '.'), '.')` and this will do the trick.

Comment: That fixes it.  I like this solution. Very clean.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
<xsl:text>SITE = '</xsl:text>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($Path, '.')>
       <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($Path, '.')"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:value-of select="$Path"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
<xsl:text>' AND PATH = '</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after($Path, '.')"/>
<xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
```

Simply takes the part before the first dot and puts it into the first condition, then puts the part after the first dot into the second condition. If there is no dot in the Path, this has to be handled as special case for the first condition, because then substring-before and -after return an empty string. It has not to be handled specifially for the second condition.

Answer (score 0):

A late answer, but the simplest correct XSLT 2.0 solution is...

```
<xsl:value-of select="string-join( 'SITE = ', substring-before(concat(Path,'.'),'.'),
                              ' AND PATH = ', substring-after(Path,'.'), ' '), '''')" />
```

Comment: This is nice, but I find the other solutions make the XSLT file more readable by keeping the text (in this case SQL) separate from the code where possible.

Comment: No worries. That being the case, you might consider putting your SQL words in a look-up table. That gives your the best separation of all.